# Default value of python get function

Tags: python, dictionary

If the default value passed to python `get` function (for dictionaries) is an expression, is it evaluated only when the key is not found? Let's consider the following example.

```py
myDiction = {"a":1,"b":2}
val = myDiction.get("c",pow(2,3)-5)
```

Is that math expression `pow(2,3)-5` evaluated or not?

Comment: As noted, the easiest way to answer these questions is to try them, with some kind of debugging if need be. But also, you should know that of course it is evaluated because of *how function calling works*; `get(...)` cannot be evaluated until the `(...)` is.

Answer (score 4):

It's not hard to test by passing your own function.

```
def someF():
    print("called")
    return 3

myDiction = {"a":1,"b":2}

myDiction.get("a",someF())
```

Prints: "called". So yes it is evaluated, like you would expect from any argument passed to to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't we find out?

```
>>> d = {1:2}
>>> d.get(1, print('default') or 3)
default
2
>>> d.get(2, print('default') or 3)
default
3
```

As you can see, function arguments are evaluated before being passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

It will be evaluated anyway.

Try this:

```
def test_func():
    print("run")
    return 3


myDiction = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
val = myDiction.get("a", test_func())
print(val)
```

You can see that even though `a` exists in the `myDiction`, the "run" message is printed.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wishing for a "lazy" version of `dict.get` that would allow passing a callable which will be called only if the key is missing a very long time now.

We don't have it yet, but one can implement that quite easily.

```
from collections import UserDict

def lazy_default_func():
    print('in lazy_default_func')
    return 7

def lazy_default_func_with_args(*args, **kwargs):
    print('in lazy_default_func_with_args', 'args', args, 'kwargs', kwargs)
    return 7

class MyDict(UserDict):
    def get(self, item, default=None, *args, **kwargs):
        print('in get')
        if item in self:
            return self[item]
        if not callable(default):
            return default
        return default(*args, **kwargs)


d = MyDict({'a': 1})
print(d.get('a', lazy_default_func))
print(d.get('b', lazy_default_func))
print(d.get('b', lazy_default_func_with_args, 'arg1'))
```

outputs

```
in get
1
in get
in lazy_default_func
7
in get
in lazy_default_func_with_args args ('arg1',) kwargs {}
7
```